# Converting a char "number" into a real int

Tags: c++

I'm wanting to take the input of a user (mathematic expression) and push it onto a stack. Then I want to run it through some rules which ask if its a '(', a number, or an operator '+'. My problem is so far I don't know how to tell, specifically stating inside the while loop's first if statement, if a char is "actually" a number. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stack>

int main()
{
    std::stack<char> myStack;    // initializing the stack
    char line[40]; 
    cin.getline(line, 40);       // this and the proceeding line get the input

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        myStack.push(line[i]);   //pushing all of the char onto the stack.

    while (!myStack.empty()) {
        if (myStack item = a number) {
        // ^ this is where it doesn't compile.
        //   I need to figure out how to find out if a char is a number
            cout << item << endl;
        }
        else if (myStack.empty()) {
            myStack.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that `cin` can read integers directly?

Comment: Something is a number if > '0' and < '9'

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Actually, it's >= resp. <= (unless 1-based octal encoding ;))

Comment: `by the way, welcome() is nothing more than welcome text so nothing to worry about` Then it does not need to form part of your testcase _at all_ and can be entirely removed.

Comment: @leemes You are correct, twice as your answer is better.

Comment: Also, there is [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)

Comment: All characters are numbers. You want to know if a characters is a digit, which is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **isdigit** function:

```
isdigit(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a function is C++ called isdigit, it checks if a character is a decimal digit.

```
if(isdigit(your_char)) //Then it's a number
```

Comment: `char` is a keyword, you cannot name a variable like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `isdigit()` in the stdlib that will answer this question for you.

There is no magic to it, however. Digits, in ASCII, are just `chars` in the range `48-57`, `48` being `'0'` and `57` being `'9'`.

```
char isdigit(char d) {
    return (d >= 48) && (d <= 57);
}
```

Comment: At least use '0' and '9' - reading ASCII magic numbers is a pain.

Comment: No. The code I wrote was meant to point out how digit characters are just numbers in that range. By writing it as `'0' - '9'` I would'be been abstracting my own point.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: However, ASCII is not guaranteed, so these values may simply be incorrect. _Do_ use `'0'` and `'9'`. Downvoted.

Comment: (It's also irresponsible to imply that this is the code the OP should use.)

Comment: Eh? I explicitly said there is a function in the stdlib for this. What's up with you people haha! Is this the ASCII police?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, if all you want is to find if a char is a number or not. Please cast it to int and check if it is between the ascii values of 48 and 57, both included.

```
bool CheckIfNum(char chartToCheck)
{
    int aciiOfChar = (int) charToCheck;

    if (asciiOfChar >= 48 && asciiOfChar <= 57)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

you can also use std::isdigit function

Comment: At least use '0' and '9' - reading ASCII magic numbers is a pain

Comment: 2 years, 4 months, is sufficient time to learn how to format posts, please! There's even a handy preview pane when you're writing your post, so you know how it'll look.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: And those values are not even necessarily correct.

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelDorgan said about pain, this will only work on systems that use ASCII. Granted, this is likely to be the vast majority of systems the OP is likely to use, but still... You ought to really express your *intent* in your code. This code doesn't do that.